# Hibernate returning old object in new transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate's entityManager to try and update an object. My code looks something like :

```
public A updateA(Aid,A)
    a = update(Aid, A);
    aNew = find(A.class,Aid);

    if(aNew.equals(a)){
        System.out.println("Expected Behaviour");
    }
}

public <E> E update(String id,E e) {
    E en=(E) find(e.getClass(),id);

    if(en!=null){
        e = em.merge(e);
        em.flush();
    }
    return e;
}

public <E> E find(Class<E> clazz, String id) {
    return em.find(clazz, id);
}
```

When I call the method `updateA` , it prints `Expected Behaviour`. However when I try and call `find(A.class,Aid)` after calling `updateA(Aid,A)` , the object returned is not the updated object but the older one.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you identifing old vs. new?

Comment: The changes made on `a` before calling `updateA` are not coming up when calling `find `

Comment: do you perform operations in the same transaction or in two differents ?

Comment: In two different transactions

Comment: if you are using two different transactions and in the first one you already get the object you need to refresh it after the second transaction occured.

Comment: @JEY : The error is occurring even if I don't get the object in the first transaction.

Comment: try to refresh anyway.